# Ubuntu 19.10 stuck at logo splash screen after update and recovery-mode also not working

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, driver, nvidia, boot

I had Ubuntu 19.04 in my MSI GL63 and I switched to Intel from Nvidia server settings for battery saving.

Everything was working fine until I decided to switch it back to NVIDIA. It asked me to reboot my system after which I encountered a black screen right after login.

I tried many fixes including purging all Nvidia related files and reinstalling the drivers and system upgrades but nothing worked. I found out the recommended driver by `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` after which I installed using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440`. Also tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Ubuntu 19.10 had been released and I decided to upgrade from TTY by CTRL+ALT+F2 hoping it would work. But now I don't even reach the login screen and it is stuck at the Ububtu logo with 5 dots.

I tried running recovery mode but only command line root access works. I even uncommented `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` in vi editor. I also tried to remove Nvidia drivers by `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` I also edited the GRUB file by adding `nomodeset` and `nomodeset=0` but nothing works.

I have a dual booted system with Windows 10 Pro.

GPU - NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050

Comment: [You already asked this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187341/ubuntu-19-10-stuck-at-logo-splash-screen-after-update-and-recovery-mode-also-not) - why are you reposting it here where it's completely off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

In the GRUB file replace `$vt_handoff` with `nouveau.modeset=0`, that worked for me whereas adding `nomodeset=0` did not.

Comment: Thanks! I did manage to get in with this but was still facing driver problems. I decided to go with a fresh install